# python tkinter entry command can't convert to int

Tags: python, input, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Trying to get used to the tkinter gui but I'm running into a problem with setting up an input box.  I wanted to make a simple number guessing program using Entry to input an integer and a button to submit the guess. I'm getting an str to int conversion error when I use int(GuessBox.get()) and I'm not sure what to do.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def makeAGuess():
    guess = int(GuessBox.get())
    print(guess)

    if guess == Answer:
        print("you got it!")
        return False
    elif guess > Answer:
        print("Too High, try again")
        return True
    else :
        print("Too low, try again")
        return True

Answer = random.randint(1, 100)


main = Tk()
label = Label(main, text = "Guess a number")
label.pack()
GuessBox = Entry(master = main)
GuessBox.pack()
submitGuess = Button(master = main, text = "Submit Guess", command = makeAGuess())
submitGuess.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: You say you get an exception, but you haven't posted it. Please give the full error, including the traceback. Your code also doesn't match what you say - you never call `int()`.

Comment: what is returned from `GuessBox.get()` when you get this error, is it all digits?

Comment: Alright, updated my post

Comment: @user2426318 Your question happened to get answered here, but in future, please attach the **full** error with **full traceback** - it makes tracking down the bug much, much simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the function as an object, don't call it.

```
submitGuess = Button( master = main, text = "Submit Guess", command = makeAGuess )
```

Otherwise makeAGuess is called when the Button is created, but not passed any arguments.
With this change your code works perfectly for me.

Comment: AHHH, now it works, awesome!  Thanks, thats been annoying me for the past hour!

Comment: No problem. Coming from Java, the functions are objects thing is a big change. This stuff would be hidden in the reflection packages. Does mean you can do cool stuff like pass a function into another function, or store a list of functions...